# Is there a Java Map class that satisfies these needs?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashtable

Is there a Java Map class that satisfies these functionalities:

1. It's a generic class with the form `UnknownMap<Key, Object>`, I plan to use it in a node based application where each node in stored in this map and corresponds to a float value object like `UnknownMap<Float, Node>`.
2. It can store objects that can map to the same float value, so for example:

```
UnknownMap<Float, String> map = new UnknownMap<Float, String>();
map.put(1, "a");
map.put(2, "b");
map.put(3, "c");
map.put(1, "d");
System.out.println(map);
```

Would print out: `{1="a", 1="d", 2="b", 3="c"}` as opposed to: `{1="d", 2="b", 3="c"}`.

3. It has a method called `subMap` that returns a map with all the nodes within a key range, similar to `TreeMap.subMap`.
4. It must perform a binary search on the float key values to retrieve the correct object, as opposed to iterating through the whole collection. It needs to be fast since there will likely be thousands if not millions of nodes.

Does such a class exist, or will I have to write one from scratch?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Guava's `TreeMultimap`.

Comment: No - because a `Map` by definition cannot have duplicate keys. If there were flexibility in your data structure then you can work this out with a couple different `Map` implementations.

Comment: Poor title, lacking specifics. Your question is not clear. I am guessing that you want to map a key to a collection of values rather than a single value. If so, this has been addressed many times already on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Map.computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function))
Try it like this:

The first time the key is encountered, it creates a list and adds the string to it.  The next time, it just adds the string to the list.  This is one technique for mapping multiple values to the same key.

```
Map<Float,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();      
map.computeIfAbsent(10f, k->new ArrayList<>()).add("a");
System.out.println(map);
map.computeIfAbsent(10f, k->new ArrayList<>()).add("b");
System.out.println(map);                 
map.computeIfAbsent(30f, k->new ArrayList<>()).add("c");
System.out.println(map);                 
map.computeIfAbsent(30f, k->new ArrayList<>()).add("d");
System.out.println(map);                 
map.computeIfAbsent(10f, k->new ArrayList<>()).add("e");
System.out.println(map);
```

Prints the following after each addition to see the map changing.

```
{10.0=[a]}
{10.0=[a, b]}
{30.0=[c], 10.0=[a, b]}
{30.0=[c, d], 10.0=[a, b]}
{30.0=[c, d], 10.0=[a, b, e]}
```

You could also concatenate new strings to the existing string using a similar technique with [Map.compute()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)).  Because the variable in a lambda must be effectively final, this is most easily done by isolating the map in a method.

```
Map<Float, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
add(10f, "a", map2);
add(10f, "b", map2);
add(30f, "c", map2);
add(30f, "d", map2);
add(10f, "e", map2);
        
map2.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
30.0=c, d
10.0=a, b, e
```

The method

```
    
public static void add(float key, String value, Map<Float, String> map) {
    map.compute(key,
            (k, v) -> v == null ? value : v + ", " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TreeMap will do the job. Make the 'value' part a List (or possibly Set) to deal with the 'one key can map to multiple values' clause:

```
public void put(float k, String v) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(k, k_ -> new ArrayList<String>()).add(v);
}
```

for example.

Comment: The syntax is `map.putIfAbsent(50f, new ArrayList<String>()).add("a");`  And first time for the key will throw an NPE.

Comment: Er, actually, my error is I meant to write computeIfAbsent there. I'll go ahead and edit it.